# Need to extract string from a file

Tags: unix

```
<token text="everyone"/></string></equals></in></filter></or></and><in><scope text="/hardwiring.excludequery"/><token text="taloglsppublishedº00051974"/></in></andnot>) MANAGED(0, 0) STATS(0.0213, 0.0006, 1))]
```

Suppose i have this type of multiple lines a file and I need to get only the  **STATS(0.0213, 0.0006, 1)** part to be extracted from the multiple lines.

Please suggest a way to this and also explain the command used.??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep`,

```
grep -Eo 'STATS\([^)]*\)' yourfile
```

(OR)

```
grep -o 'STATS([^)]*)' yourfile
```